# Не получается обновить composer

Tags: composer

Использую встроенный в openserver composer.

Пробую:

```
 composer global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:~1.0.3"
```

Получаю:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method
>   Fxp\Composer\AssetPlugin\Package\Version\VersionParser::parseLinks()
>   in
>   C:\Users\dev\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\fxp\composer-asset-plugin\Repository\VcsPackageFilter.php
>   on line 272

```
composer self-update проходит
```

Comment: Зачем глобально устанавливать компонент? Ошибка при установке компонента или при выполнении вашего кода? Вызов VersionParser::parseLinks() есть только в версиях пакета меньше 1.0.3, после установки этой версии этой проблемы вообще быть не должно.

Comment: при composer update та же ошибка

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно удалить папку fxp в `C:\Users\dev\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor`

Answer (score 0):

Удалите папку vendor и сделайте `composer update`